# $ throws parsing error: unexpected token in React App

Tags: javascript, jquery, directory, directory-structure

I'm currently building my personal portfolio in React with some jquery/gulp/sass action, and it's my first time with these libs/toolkits/stylesheets. I've bitten off more than I can chew. At present, I am integrating a responsive template from [html5up.net](https://html5up.net/) into Facebook's *[Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started)* build.

I'm having a hard time adapting the former's architecture into the React App without breaking all the dependencies. Cut-and-pasting the relevant bits has resulted in moderate success, but I've run into this snag with the main.js file:

```
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $body = $('body');
```

tosses up the parsing error "unexpected token error". My understanding is that these lines `$` is employing `jquery` functionality to `select` the `window object` but I'm not sure what the point of defining `select window/body` as `select window/body` would be. This looks tautological to me.

As for what's causing the issue, I suspect it has something to do with
the way my `main.js` relates to the jquery file. Here's a sketch of my 
file tree For reference:

```
>root
>>public
>>>main.js

>>src
>>>js
>>>>jquery.min.js
```

My question(s):

- What's the cause of the parsing error?
- Why does jquery need to define `window` tautologically?
- If the cause of this problem is `main.js` not having access to the jquery library, how can I fix that?

Comment: The `$` should be passed in to the IIFE, check the end of that block of code. It should look something like `})(jQuery)`. `Why does jquery need to define window tautologically` it doesn't. That block of code is just declaring a jQuery object containing the `window`, for some reason. It's a little redundant.

Comment: The end of that code does pass in `$`; it looks identical to your suggested syntax, unfortunately:

`})(jQuery);`

So, now I'm wondering if I just have it's usage all wrong. I have incorporated this code into the app.js file, so it's inside a div. Does that make sense?